# How do I update a numpy array using a list containing indexes of that array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am programming a chess game in Python 3, and I have a numpy array in the shape of a chessboard like so:

```
start_pos = np.array([[r, n, b, q, k, b, n, r],
                      [p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p],
                      [e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e],
                      [e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e],
                      [e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e],
                      [e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e],
                      [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
                      [R, N, B, Q, K, B, N, R]])
```

Just for context, these are piece objects. I am currently programming the knight, and I want the square that the knight leaves to be changed to e (empty square). With my current code, I have a list of possible squares like so:

```
possible_squares = [start_pos[sq_rank_num+2, sq_file_num+1], start_pos[sq_rank_num+2, sq_file_num-1], start_pos[sq_rank_num-2, sq_file_num+1], start_pos[sq_rank_num-2, sq_file_num-1], start_pos[sq_rank_num+1, sq_file_num+2], start_pos[sq_rank_num+1, sq_file_num-2], start_pos[sq_rank_num-1, sq_file_num+2], start_pos[sq_rank_num-1, sq_file_num-2]]
```

where sq_rank_num and sq_file_num are the rank and file numbers of the square to move to respectively. However, when I run the  following code:

```
for x in possible_squares:
    if x == N:
        x = e
        start_pos[sq_rank_num, sq_file_num] = N
        return f"You have played the move {piece}{square}"
    return f"Illegal move"
```

the x = e doesn't work. I need the square that contains the knight to become e. I am sure that this is what is causing the issue, as I have tested everything else, and it all works as intended. As it is now, the knight moves, but leaves a duplicated version of itself on the square it left, since the square doesn't become empty. If someone could tell me a method of fixing this issue, or provide some code that does with an explanation, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = e` is not the way to update a numpy array, you need to use indexing like you have done here `start_pos[sq_rank_num, sq_file_num] = N`. But the way you have constructed the for loop (of what you have showed anyway) does not provide any indexes to work with.

For example, if the beginning position of the knight is

```
start_pos[sq_rank_num, sq_file_num]
```

Then the way to update the array would be

```
start_pos[sq_rank_num, sq_file_num] = e
```

You could add an extra layer in the for loop to get the indexes

```
for idx in [(x, y) for x in range(start_pos.shape[0]) for y in range(start_pos.shape[1])]
    for x in possible_squares:
        if start_pos[idx] == x and x == N:
            start_pos[idx] = e
```

However, I would possibly look at redesigning your code. If you are taking a starting square as input along with a target square, it makes sense to validate both of those squares, and then if the move is possible update your board based on the source and target coordinates.